# How to get all supported CultureInfos of an ResourceManager instance?

Tags: .net

I want to retrieve all the supported CultureInfos of an ResourceManager instance so I can give the user a feedback which languages are supported. Am I missing something or is there no easy way to retrieve such a list?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but here's an alternative idea.

If your program is set up such that it uses localized resource files to produce satellite assemblies, or similar resource-based DLLs, then presumably the names of the folders that the satellite assemblies are in, or else the file names of the DLLs themselves, will include the information you need. So you can examine these folder names or filenames and see what is (presumably) available.